# Falcon - how to validate incoming requests against Swagger specification?

Tags: python, json, validation, swagger, falconframework

What is the most convenient and comprehensive way of validating incoming requests in Falcon views against Swagger 2.0 specification written in json?

I used to do the same for Pyramid apps with great tool called [pyramid_swagger](https://github.com/striglia/pyramid_swagger). It was seamlessly pluggable on application level and it attached `validated` dict to the `request` object. It contained everything, including path parameters, querystring parameters and of course body params.

I tried [Flex](https://github.com/pipermerriam/flex) and [falcon-json-io](https://bitbucket.org/garymonson/falcon-json-io), but couldn't make it do what I need. Also [serve_swagger](https://github.com/crowdwave/serve_swagger) is completely different story, I don't need an autogenerated API.

At this point I am considering writing my own tool or extending Flex or falcon-json-io. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Hi, how do you generate swagger documentation for your api written in falcon?

Comment: @AyushiDalmia I don't. I write it myself with consultation with the end user of future API. In my case I do it together with our front-end developers. To _generate_ Swagger docs would mean that it's generated from something. What would that be? A whiteboard after product meeting? :) My point is that you need to document API **before** implementing it. At least that's my opinion.

Comment: Gotcha! I used http://editor.swagger.io/#/ and generated my json file. However, I am not able to integrate well with the index.html in the dist folder of the Swagger-UI repo. Any pointers on how to add the json? Through url or spec?

Comment: I don't use Swagger UI yet. You should search for answers or post a new question if you cannot find anything appropriate.

Comment: In case anyone is looking for an answer, I have put together a small lib that does it: https://github.com/gwaramadze/falguard

Comment: @gwaramadze Your library should be an answer.

Comment: @AlisterLee hey thanks! It actually was, but local "bureaucracy" got it deleted...